# How to merge duplicate rows using expressions in Spark Dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I merge 2 data frames by removing duplicates by comparing  columns.

```html
I have two dataframes with same column names
a.show()
+-----+----------+--------+
| name|      date|duration|
+-----+----------+--------+
|  bob|2015-01-13|       4|
|alice|2015-04-23|      10|
+-----+----------+--------+
b.show()
+------+----------+--------+
|  name|      date|duration|
+------+----------+--------+
|   bob|2015-01-12|       3|
|alice2|2015-04-13|      10|
+------+----------+--------+
```

What I am trying to do is merging of 2 dataframes to display only unique rows by applying two conditions
1.For same name duration will be sum of durations. 
2.For same name,the final date will be latest date.

```html
  

Final output will be 
final.show()
+-------+----------+--------+
| name  |      date|duration|
+-----  +----------+--------+
|  bob  |2015-01-13|       7|
|alice  |2015-04-23|      10|
|alice2 |2015-04-13|      10|
+-------+----------+--------+

I followed the following method.

//Take union of 2 dataframe
val df =a.unionAll(b)

//group and take sum
val grouped =df.groupBy("name").agg($"name",sum("duration"))

//join
val j=df.join(grouped,"name").drop("duration").withColumnRenamed("sum(duration)", "duration")

and I got 
+------+----------+--------+
|  name|      date|duration|
+------+----------+--------+
|   bob|2015-01-13|       7|
| alice|2015-04-23|      10|
|   bob|2015-01-12|       7|
|alice2|2015-04-23|      10|
+------+----------+--------+
```

How can I now remove duplicates by comparing dates. 
    Will it be possible by running sql queries after registering it as table.
    I am a beginner in SparkSQL and I feel like my way of approaching this problem is weird. Is there any better way to do this kind of data processing.

Comment: What is the final result you want ?

Comment: Hi Srini,check final.show() 
I am trying to eliminate duplicate rows for same names by summing the duration  in duplicate rows and displaying only latest date in date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do `max(date)` in `groupBy()`. No need to do `join` the `grouped` with `df`.

```
// In 1.3.x, in order for the grouping column "name" to show up,
val grouped = df.groupBy("name").agg($"name",sum("duration"), max("date"))

// In 1.4+, grouping column "name" is included automatically.
val grouped = df.groupBy("name").agg(sum("duration"), max("date"))
```

Comment: Thank you ,that  worked.
I tried to use join thinking that,if I have other columns in table,I will have to merge them to final table after performing the calculations in time and date fields.